# Visualize sqlite data for user in a browser

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I am trying to see if some of my connected devices are working properly or not(starting and stopping them) by defining some end points (in Python):

```
import sqlite3 
import csv
import requests
from nose.tools import *
import json
import time

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = db.cursor();
serverIP = "http://127.0.0.1:port"
Version = "ver"

response = request.get("http://127.0.0.1:port/ver/On").text
print response

eq_(response, "{status: 'OK'}\n}")

print "Start qr-Scanner"
data = {'callback':'http://localhost:post/ver/testPost/'}
url = "%s/%s/%s" % (serverIP, Version, "test")
response = requests.post(url, data=data).json()
print response

time.sleep(10)

print "Stop qr-scanner"
url = "%s/%s/%s" % (serverIP, Version, "test")
response = requests.post(url, data="").json()
```

Once the test of each device is finished I get user input and I save it in a table in sqlite database:

```
    while True:
         **device1value** = raw_input("Invalid Input. Does this device work fine? Y/N: ")
         if device not in ("y","Y", "n", "N"):
             **device1value** = raw_input("Invalid Input. Does device work fine? Y/N: ")
         else:
             print ("device is working fine")

   CREATE TABLE test(device1 TEXT, device2 TEXT, device3 Text, 
                       device4 TEXT)
''')
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO test(device1, device2, device3, device4, device5)
                  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)''', (device1value,device2value, device3value, device4value, device5value))

db.commit()
print('devices Has Been Tested')
```

How can I visualize data saved in my table? What would be the best way to show the test results to user?

Comment: Any report generation tool?

Comment: yes,exactly. I want to show the result of each test for devices in a table after all tests are finished. is saving results in a sqlite database a good idea?

Comment: That doesn't matter, as it just has to be saved somewhere. My answer has a simple example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward report-generation tool from sqlite seems to be the sqlite command itself:

```
sqlite3 -batch -csv test.db 'select device1 from test where lower(device1) = 'n'`
```

Will get the non-working values of device1. You might want to add a timestamp column to your table and add that to the select statement as it doesn't appear to make that information available.